# Does this series $ \sum \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}} $ converge :

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Does this series $\displaystyle \sum \dfrac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}} $ converge :

**Attempt :**

$u_n:=\dfrac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}>0$

$(\ln n)^{\ln n}=\exp\bigg(\ln n \cdot \ln(\ln n)\bigg)=n^{\ln(\ln n)}$

$\ln(\ln n)>2\iff n>e^{e^2}$

So for all $n>e^{e^2}$ $n^{\ln(\ln n)}>n^2\iff\dfrac{1}{n^{\ln(\ln n)}}<\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ we conclude that $u_n=\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$

So $\sum u_n$ converges

**MY QUESTION IS (That is not a duplicate)**

The correction suggests to use the root test, and it says that $u_n^{1/n}= \dfrac{1}{\ln n}$, but **I can't find this result.** May I have an explanation?

Comment: @GuyFsone I think the problem is that the OP has already proven it but for some reason was told to use the root test, and in a way that itself looks incorrect. Thus I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  Please read the question first

Comment: @stu Yes, sorry.

Comment: At the risk of picking nits, please add the limits of summation to the expression about which you want to ask convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question you asked....

The root test does not work here. The $n$th root of the $n$th term is:

$$u_n^{1/n}=(\ln n)^{-\ln n/n}$$

As $n\to\infty$, that expression approaches $1$, so the root test is inconclusive for this series.

To be clear, it is *not true* that $u_n^{1/n}=\frac{1}{\ln n}$, which you can see by plugging in some value for $n$.

Comment: @ thanks, so the correction has got a typo thanks

Comment: Yeah, either that or the original problem does. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method works. The answer you have been given is incorrect, unless you have a typo in the question and it should be $u_n=\frac1{(\log n) ^n}$.

Comment: ok understood thanks